# I am trying to search and get YouTube video on my webpage

Tags: php

I am trying to search and get YouTube videos on my webpage. But I have some error. How can I fix it?

The HTML code is:

```html
<h2>Search Videos by keyword using YouTube Data API V3</h2>
<div class="search-form-container">
    <form id="keywordForm" method="post" action="">
        <div class="input-row">
            Search Keyword : <input class="input-field" type="search"
                id="keyword" name="keyword"
                placeholder="Enter Search Keyword">
        </div>

        <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" name="submit"
            value="Search">
    </form>
</div>
```

Now moving to the PHP code where I used iframe for the video title and use my own created API from the developer account. But when I run the code I get an error about MAX_RESULT.

And the PHP code and YouTube API is here:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) )
     {
        $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];

        if (empty($keyword))
        {
            $response = array(
                  "type" => "error",
                  "message" => "Please enter the keyword."
                );
        }
    }
?>


<?php
if(!empty($response)) {
?>
<div class="response <?php echo $response["type"]; ?>
    ">
    <?php echo $response["message"]; ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) )
{

  if (!empty($keyword))
  {
    $apikey = 'AIzaSyAjowKxG2mRdr7p1N-3RtBd-BWAgjbf87g';

    $googleApiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' . $keyword . '&maxResults=' . MAX_RESULTS . '&key=' . $apikey;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $googleApiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($response);
    $value = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
?>

<div class="result-heading">About <?php echo MAX_RESULTS; ?> Results</div>
<div class="videos-data-container" id="SearchResultsDiv">

<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < MAX_RESULTS; $i++) {
        $videoId = $value['items'][$i]['id']['videoId'];
        $title = $value['items'][$i]['snippet']['title'];
        $description = $value['items'][$i]['snippet']['description'];
        ?>

<div class="video-tile">
<div  class="videoDiv">
    <iframe id="iframe" style="width:100%;height:100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $videoId; ?>"
data-autoplay-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $videoId; ?>?autoplay=1"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="videoInfo">
<div class="videoTitle"><b><?php echo $title; ?></b></div>
<div class="videoDesc"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
</div>
</div>
           <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Error message:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant MAX_RESULTS - assumed 'MAX_RESULTS' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\youtube\youtubeVideoAPI.php on line 48 . On my text editor line, 48 code is $googleApiUrl = 'googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' . $keyword . '&maxResults=' . MAX_RESULTS . '&key=' . $apikey;

Comment: "_I get an error about MAX_RESULT_" What is the _exact_ error message you get? Please add in your post

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer please have a look at the error now. Notice: Use of undefined constant MAX_RESULTS - assumed 'MAX_RESULTS' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\youtube\youtubeVideoAPI.php on line 48 . On my text editor line, 48 code is $googleApiUrl = 'googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' . $keyword . '&maxResults=' . MAX_RESULTS . '&key=' . $apikey; Please help

Comment: You use `MAX_RESULTS` in your code but it isn't defined anywhere (we can see). That APIKey is for testing only, right? Because everybody who can read this post can use this APIKey now.

Comment: I defined MAX_RESULTS as define('MAX_RESULT' , 1);
but after that the error comes id already mentioned in a comment.

Comment: "_I defined MAX_RESULTS as define('MAX_RESULT' , 1);_" No you didn't. With that code you defined `MAX_RESULT`, not `MAX_RESULTS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check, if you have defined the `MAX_RESULTS` constant in your code.

If you want to define a constant, you can do it this way:

```php
define('MAX_RESULTS', 1); // I don't know, what value you need, so you can the 1 for anything you want
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer please have a look at the error now.
Notice: Use of undefined constant MAX_RESULTS - assumed 'MAX_RESULTS' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\youtube\youtubeVideoAPI.php on line 48 .
On my text editor line, 48 code is 
    $googleApiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' . $keyword . '&maxResults=' . MAX_RESULTS . '&key=' . $apikey;
Please help

Comment: @MohsinSohail It looks like you still haven't defined the `MAX_RESULTS` constant. You must do this before any code, that uses this constant, is called. Try adding the snippet in my answer at the begging of your code (for example before `if (isset($_POST['submit']) )`).